# Is there a way to combine categories and their hierarchy into the admin listing page?

Tags: plugins, categories, taxonomy

A simple question for a plugin that I would imagine must exist yet I can't find it.

I want the standard listing page of posts (for my custom post type) to show all the posts within a  tree like hierarchical structure where they are all grouped by categories that the posts are assigned to.

I thought I'd found this with the "Nested Pages" plugin but it doesn't actually work with categories.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score -3):

I used the content views plugin to make the list ( https://www.contentviewspro.com/ ) and then just put in short codes for each category list, separated by headings.

You can see the result here:

http://leakagemanagement.dk/white-papers-and-reports/

All the best
Michael